# Display PDF file with uiwebview cannot zoom out

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, uiwebview

My application fix to landscape only.
In my view controller I use UIWebview for showing pdf file.
I can zoom in and zoom out by pinch 2 finger but when trying to pinch to zoom out,it stops automatically animate to scale 1.0
I want to zoom out for showing all area in my pdf(A4 size vertical) but
when left finger from pinch I want to set that scale not back to 1.0.
Is it possible?
Here is my code :

```
  _previewView.scalesPageToFit = YES;  
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;  
_previewView.opaque = NO;  
_previewView.delegate = self;  
_previewView.scrollView.delegate =self;  
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:savePath]];  
[_previewView loadRequest:request];
```

Comment: I solved a similar thing and finaly i used this library: https://github.com/mindbrix/UIImage-PDF and make image from pdf document

Answer (score 0):

```
  NSString *openURL = kAboutURL;

UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 64, self.view.frame.size.width , self.view.frame.size.height-64)];
NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL URLWithString:openURL];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
[webView loadRequest:request];
webView.delegate = self;
webView.scalesPageToFit=YES;
[self.view addSubview:webView];
```